# How can I insert a '-' in my string?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that can look like this: `12345`, this `123456` or this: `1234567`.

I'd like to make each string look like this: `123-45`, this: `1234-56` or this: `12345-67`.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: do you mean have the a dash then the last 2 digits?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, Daniel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string myString = "1234567";   
if(myString.Length > 1)
   string dashed = myString.Insert(myString.Length - 2, "-");
```

EDIT: Added check based on comment, but depends on how such strings should be handled. (e.g. dashed even if length = 2?)

Comment: Awesome!  I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The problem with this approach is it'll throw an exception for strings of length <= 1

Comment: True. You could add a simple `if` statement `if(myString.Length > 1)` to check if the string is valid. Depends on if the OP will come across such strings and, if so, how they are to be handled.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at String.Format(), My guess is you want something like String.Format("{0:##-##}",< value >);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Examples shown with powershell, which uses the same corelibs

```
PS C:\Users\Phyx> [string]::Format("{0:##-##}",1234)
12-34
PS C:\Users\Phyx> [string]::Format("{0:##-##}",123445)
1234-45
PS C:\Users\Phyx> [string]::Format("{0:##-##}",12)
-12
PS C:\Users\Phyx> [string]::Format("{0:0#-##}",12)
00-12
PS C:\Users\Phyx> [string]::Format("{0:##-##}",122)
1-22
```

Comment: This works for numeric values, if the value is a string already it won't do anything to it since it's already a string. I assume the OP already has the value as a numerical variable, or he needs to call Parse or TryParse, which would also validate his input.

Answer (score 6):

```
string s = "teststring";
string newString = s.Insert(s.Length-2,"-");
```

This is assuming you want the '-' to appear two from the end :-)

This could be handy (untested)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a string and and inserts a spacer character at 
    /// a specifed distance from the end
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">string to modify</param>
    /// <param name="spacer">string to insert</param>
    /// <param name="positionFromEnd">insertion point</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected string AddSpacer(string input, string spacer, int positionFromEnd)
    {
        string outputString = string.Empty;

        if (input.Length >= positionFromEnd)
        {
            outputString = input.Insert(input.Length - positionFromEnd, spacer);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The position you tried to insert the spacer into doesn't exist");
        }

        return outputString;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you want to add a dash two characters before the end of the string.

```
string number = "12345";

if(number.Length > 2)
    string result = number.Insert(number.Length-2, "-");
else
    //error checking
```